# Pagination issues when using setspace

Tags: page-breaking, setspace

I have a document which was drafted using `\baselinestretch` to set the line spacing.  In order to prevent extra spacing in footnotes, I'm trying to switch to the `setspace` package.

Since the end result should be to compactify footnotes, I would expect the page count to either decrease or stay the same.  Strangely, it increases.  Part of the problem was the increase in vertical spacing around display equations.  I was able to prevent that with the `nodisplayskipstretch` option.

The remaining problem seems to be related to a change in pagination behavior, as is visible in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%
% EITHER
%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
%%%%%%%%%
%  OR
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myeqn}{
  \begin{equation}
    a \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  b
  \end{equation}
}

\blindtext \footnote{A footnote}
\myeqn
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobor-
tis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent
imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lec-
tus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus
nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Prae-
sent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \footnote{Yet another}
\myeqn
\blindtext \footnote{One too many.}

\myeqn

\end{document}
```

Using `baselinestretch`, all three footnotes fit onto the first page, despite the 1.3x line spacing of the footnotes:
[image: baselinestretch]
On the other hand, `setspace` breaks the page earlier, even though the line spacing of the footnotes is only 1x:
[image: setspace]
Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

### EDIT:

After tinkering around with [`setspace.sty`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rf-latex/setspace/master/setspace.sty), I have discovered that the following lines are responsible:

```
% GT:  EMSH chose to omit display math part that follows.
% She wrote (see above) that the "altered spacing before and after displayed
% equations ... just looked too much".
%
% Fix up spacing before and after displayed math
% (arraystretch seems to do a fine job for inside LaTeX displayed math,
% since array and eqnarray seem to be affected as expected).
% Changing \baselinestretch and doing a font change also works if done here,
% but then you have to change @setsize to remove the call to @nomath)
%
% GT:  The \belowdisplayskip line was mistyped; now fixed, courtesy of
% David Hull.
%
% GT:  Brett Parnell has addressed EMSH's concern by replacing
% \baselinestretch by \displayskipstretch in displays, as follows.

\everydisplay\expandafter{%
  \the\everydisplay
  \abovedisplayskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayshortskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip
}
```

I would expect this code to do nothing, since the definition of `nodisplayskipstretch` is `\setdisplayskipstretch{1.0}`, but experimentation proves that this is not the case.  Thus I believe I could solve the issue by reverting the definition of `\everydisplay` after loading `setspace.sty`.  Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: this has been posted as https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On GitHub, David Carlisle proposes the following:](https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/issues/1)

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\setstretch{1.3}
```

For reference, I have a non-minimal example for which the `\setdisplayskipstretch{}` line decreases the length from 100 to 97 pages.

The two answers I have written here both produce pixelwise identical results.  Thus I am leaving both, but marking this one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The following code appears to accomplish what I wanted, by means of the solution which I suggested in the EDIT to my question:

```
\edef\oldeverydisplay{\the\everydisplay}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\oldeverydisplay}
\setstretch{1.3}
```

Specifically, this code block should replace the two `setspace` lines in the MWE.

I would appreciate any feedback on this. (I'm not so comfortable with token parameters like `\everydisplay`, so perhaps this isn't the "right" way to do things.)  I am also wondering whether this is a bug in `setspace`.